# GridView Databind not working

Tags: c#, list, gridview

I have a gridview that has a datasource of list of objects. But it seems to have an issue on the DataBind step. it does not display anything on the site.

```
List<StringTR> strResult_List = new List<StringTR>();

foreach (TSService.STs ST in ST_Returned_list) //I'm converting ST_Returned_list to StringResult as ST_Returned_list has some custom type fields and they are not working with Gridview
{
    strResult_List.Add(new StringResult(ST));
}

ResultsGridView.DataSource = strResult_List;
                    ResultsGridView.DataBind(); // this is where it is failing. when I step through it, it says "Step into: Stepping over method without symbols" 


public class StringResult
    {
         string str_SName { get; set; }
         string IPAddressUsed { get; set; }
         string BTypeUsed { get; set; }
         string SResult { get; set; }

        public StringResult(TestScriptsService.Sel_Test ST)
        {

                str_SName = ST.SName.ToString();
                IPAddressUsed = ST.IPAddressUsed;
                BTypeUsed = ST.BTypeUsed.ToString();
                SResult = ST.SResult.ToString();

        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you getting an error on DataBind or does it just do nothing?

Comment: it appears to do nothing.. in the output window of VS.. It says the following right when it tries to execute ResultsGridView.DataBind() step. Btw - I can get the contents of strResult_List using Labels on the HTML page. It seems to be having issues only when i bind it to the gridview. 

Step into: Stepping over method without symbols 'System.Web.UI.AsyncPostBackTrigger.OnEvent'
Step into: Stepping over method without symbols 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick'
Step into: Stepping over method without symbols 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent' ....

Answer (score 0):

Place a break point at the databind step and check what is in the datasource.
This will clear the doubts.